# Is there a way to add function calls to an Automatic Property?

Tags: c#, properties

I understand how `Auto-Implemented Properties` work and how they are supposed to help. I was wondering if I could still use it somehow in a more advanced way.

Imagine I have this:

`public int SomeProperty { get; set; }`

Which is basically another way of writing the code below (but using Automatic Properties).

```
 private int _someField;
 public int SomeProperty 
 {
    get { return _someField;}
    set { _someField = value;}
 }
```

What I want to do is write:

```
 private int _someField;
 public int SomeProperty 
 {
    get { return _someField;}
    set { FunctionA(); _someField = value;}
 }
```

But using the advantages of the `Auto-Implemented Properties`. Is that possible?

I tried something like this:
`public int SomeProperty { get; set{FunctionA();} }`

But it doesn't work. Thank you everybody for the help, I know it's silly but I am curious about it.

Comment: This is an ongoing issue. See [this feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2502) on GitHub, or on [developercommunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/424379/provide-support-for-onpropertychanged-for-auto-pro.html).

Comment: Did you really need an answer? You immediately accepted that it's impossible and ignored the suggested way how your problem is __actually__ solved.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and time Alex. However Lesiak answered my question properly. What I consider an advantage of the Auto-Implemented properties is using an easy-to-read single line statement, and it's not possible to do it with the current out-of-the box c# language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not allowed. See the language spec:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#properties

> An automatically implemented property (or auto-property for short), is a non-abstract non-extern property with semicolon-only accessor bodies.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find free tool, but [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) handles this. It has trial period and some free-to-use options. Anyway take a look at **method decoration** and **AOP** frameworks.

```
using System;
using PostSharp.Aspects;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {    
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var someClass = new SomeClass();
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(someClass.Value)} = {someClass.Value}");
            someClass.Value = 42;
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(someClass.Value)} = {someClass.Value}");
        }
    }

    class SomeClass
    {
        public int Value { get; [Decorate] set; }

        private void SomeFunction()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SomeFunction called");
        }

        [Serializable, AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
        public class DecorateAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
        {
            public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
            {
                var target = (SomeClass)args.Instance;
                target.SomeFunction();

                args.Proceed(); // performs the method it applied to
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Value = 0
SomeFunction called
Value = 42
```